# Temerature and Strain images comparison & interpolation: finding offsets in X,Y coordinates systems.

Tags: optimization, interpolation, image-processing

I have two kind of 2D images from a Strain test, which show temperature and strain distributions in X and Y cordinate systems.

One is thermal image, which gives temperature T values in a 200x300 matrix form. I can calculate the distance between each pixels, so I know the X,Y cordinates in millimeters for each temerature point.

Second Image is the strain image, which shows strain values in a 500x700 matrix form. I also know their distances at X' and Y' positions.

Both of these images have different resolutions and I want to interpolate temperature values on the strain image co-ordinates. But to do so accurately, I first need to find the offset of thermal image, and then interpolate the temerpature values.

Mathematically speaking, how best can I find the optimal X & Y offsets? Since Temperature and Strain are co-related, my problem is to minimize the variance in distribution patterens between Strain and Temprature images.

Comment: To clarify, you know the relative positions of each pixel within its own image but you do not know their absolute position?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. We can use Strain image as fixed co-ordinate system and use offsets in Temperature image.

Comment: How are temperature and strain related?

Comment: There is no direct (linear/nonlinear)relationship, but for most cases, we can assume that a high strain corresponds to high temerature.

Comment: Well, if there is no other relationship besides a high-point in one probably at the same physical location as a high-point in the other, then how else could you do it besides using these high-points? Are the lots of high-points? A single high-point? Could you post some pics or provide some other information? You have to remember that you probably know more about stress/temperture images than the other people here.